# Integrating Google Analytis to android app

Tags: android, analytics

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/#manifest "Add the send methods to the onStart() and onStop() methods of each of your Activities as in the following example:"

Here is the question, I have no onStart and onStop methods in my main class. Should I put that piece of code in all of my methods? Or only in specific ones? I have a lot of methods in my class (probably should do something about it...):

```
package com.something.smth;

import something.com;

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public class Main extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText input;
LinearLayout ll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    something
}

private void whatToDo() {
    something
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    something
}

private void prefdata() {
    something
}

private void printAll(int i, int examNumb) {
    something
}

private void printOutFirst(String lesson, String type, int monthD,
        int dayD, int hourD) {
    something
}

private void printOutSecond(int monthD, int dayD, int hourD) {
    something
}

private void timeleft(int mDate, int dDate, int hDate) {
    something
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    something
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    something
}
}
```

Also, should I put that piece of code in all of my class'es or only in my main (above) class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely should create those methods and put the appropriate GA calls in there.  Another option would be to build a base class and extend it so you're not duplicating code.  I have some other tricks outlined here:

http://www.aydabtudev.com/2011/03/google-analytics-tricks-for-android.html